# Post to Facebook fan page from backend?

Tags: php, api, facebook

I am trying to write a Facebook application that can post to a Facebook fan page (not a user page), using `streamPublish`. However, I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to let the backend program stay "logged in" between sessions. I've deduced that it has something to do with the session secret and key, but I've found no good examples using these.

Do you know of a good example of this? I am using the standard Facebook PHP library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience from the Fan Page aspect of this, but I know from the User standpoint you would have to have the User grant your application extended privileges so you can receive a permanent session key.

You may want to try granting extended/offline privileges to your application from the user account that created the Fan Page, since theoretically, that user can post to the Page's stream.